# Efficient way of binding events to element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one anchor element in my page

```
<a href="..." id="page">Click</a>
```

I know in jQuery we have so many ways of binding events to element like (bind, live, delegate, on).

FYI:

http://blog.tivix.com/2012/06/29/jquery-event-binding-methods/

Currently using **jquery1.8.3.min.js**. I want to know which one is standard and efficient event registration model in jQuery?

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
      $("#page").click(function(){
................................

    });
```

Can I change to bind like below code:

```
$("#page").bind("click",clickFunc);

function clickFunc()
{
..........
}
```

Which one is best practice to register the event in jQuery 1.8 ?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***best*** way is the way one can understand what's written and the one that works.
The ***smart*** way is to use what's suggested to use, in this case the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see .one()

The ***how-to*** way depends if you need to delegate your event/s to dynamically generated elements or not.

```
$('.child').on( 'click', function() { /* ... */ });
$('#parent').on( 'click', ".dyn-gen-child", function() { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

`.on` is the standard method:

```
$("#page").on("click", function() {
    .......
});
```

If the `p` element is generated dynamically, you'll have to do:

```
$(document).on("click", "#page", function() {
    .......
});
```

Comment: As a side note *-performance wise-* instead of `document` use the first *non-dynamically-generated* parent element as selector.

Comment: Yes. Good point. Then it doesn't have to search as far through the DOM.

Comment: Exactly, due to *event bubbling* pretty expensive if `document` is the last horizon.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after jQuery 1.7, `on` is the preferred way to bind events rather than `bind`. So I prefer `on` API.

And then:

```
click(function(){})
```

is just the shortcut of

```
on('click',function(){})
```

Internally, they are actually the same -- when the `on` param is `event, handler`, but `on` is more general because it can do more than simple `onClick`(example:event delegation) see:[link](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

so I recommend `on`

Comment: wasn't it from v. 1.7?